# Requests code to scrape paginated websites

Tags: python, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape several numbered pages (in years) from Wikipedia:

```
for year in range(1991, 2000, 1):
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + str(year)
    source = requests.get(url)

x = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")

x
```

However, when inspecting 'x' I see that I downloaded only the 1999 page. How can I scrape all the pages I need years 1991 to 2000?

And put them in a dict with for each year (key) the text (value)?

Comment: Please consider using the [MediaWiki API](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Main_page). Not only does that put less strain on their servers, you can get the results in an easy to process form, eg JSON. FWIW, Stack Overflow has a couple of related tags: [tag:mediawiki-api] and [tag:wikipedia-api].

Comment: Thanks. Ill look into that api. I need to practice Requests as well. Would it be ok to use time-out or still too much for wikipedia?

Comment: Hey,.you need to put your x code in the for loop..

Comment: The Requests module works very nicely with the MediaWiki API. In fact, the Python example code in the API docs uses Requests. If you use the API properly then you'll (probably) consume _far_ less bandwidth than page scraping, so you may not have to worry about slowing down your script.

Comment: (cont) From [API:Etiquette Request limit](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/API:Etiquette#Request_limit) "There is no hard and fast limit on read requests, but we ask that you be considerate and try not to take a site down. Most sysadmins reserve the right to unceremoniously block you if you do endanger the stability of their site." It takes a bit of time to learn how to use the API (and I'm only a beginner myself), but IMHO the learning curve is worth the results.

Comment: Thanks PM 2ring and Dhruv!

Answer (score 1):

Because your x is outside the for loop. Change your code to this -

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

res_dict = {}
for year in range(1991, 1994, 1):
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + str(year)
    source = requests.get(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(source.content, "html.parser")
    res_dict[year] = soup.text
```

Comment: Thanks! As also written in the reply above, I now understand that the bs command should be in the loop. However when I use your code and inspect soup, it still shows only the last year? And not all years. Also when inspecting res_dict the years are printed, but the values show "None"

Comment: Sorry there was a minor mistake in my answer. Fixed now.

Comment: No problem. I am glad it helped.

Answer (score 0):

Because `for` will loop the code, and...let's see an example:

```
for year in range(1991, 2000, 1):
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + str(year)
    source = requests.get(url)
```

Now, the first time loop, `url` is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1991`.
the  second time, the `url` is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1992`.

At the last time, the url is `https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999`. So the `source` is `requests.get(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1999)`

If you don't understand me, you can try these codes:

```
for i in range(1, 10):
    a = i
    print(a)

print(a)
```

---

So `x = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")` must inside the `for` loop like this:

```
for year in range(1991, 2000, 1):
    url = "https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + str(year)
    source = requests.get(url)

    x = BeautifulSoup(source.text, "html.parser")
    x
```

Comment: Thanks! I now understand that the bs command should be in the loop. However when I use your code and inspect x, it still shows only the last year? And not all years. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I can't understand why this code doesn't work. What does ``BeautifulSoup`` do?

Comment: It's probably a Good Idea to know a little about [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup) before answering questions that use it. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks, let me see that :)

Comment: I've just see the document and installed BeautifulSoup. And it's working perfectly at here.

Comment: Thanks Kevin and PM 2ring! Solved it by excluding BS from the loop. Stackoverflow rules.

Comment: I'm happy to hear that :)